# Implementing STFT with Pytorch gives a slightly different result than the STFT with Librose

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft, pytorch, librosa

I am trying to implement `STFT` with `Pytorch`. But the output from the `Pytorch` implementation is slightly off, when compared with the implementation from `Librosa`.

### Librosa version

```
import numpy as np
from librosa.core import stft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(3)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*50*np.linspace(0,10,2048))+np.sin(2*np.pi*20*np.linspace(0,10,2048)) + np.random.normal(scale=1,size=2048)

S_stft = np.abs(stft(y, hop_length=512, n_fft=2048,center=False))

plt.plot(S_stft)
```

[image]

### Pytorch version

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn.functional import conv1d

from scipy.signal.windows import hann

stride = 512

def create_filters(d,k,low=50,high=6000):
    x = np.arange(0, d, 1)
    wsin = np.empty((k,1,d), dtype=np.float32)
    wcos = np.empty((k,1,d), dtype=np.float32)
    start_freq = low
    end_freq = high
    # num_cycles = start_freq*d/44000.
    # scaling_ind = np.log(end_freq/start_freq)/k

    window_mask = hann(2048, sym=False) # same as 0.5-0.5*np.cos(2*np.pi*x/(k))
    for ind in range(k):
        wsin[ind,0,:] = window_mask*np.sin(2*np.pi*ind/k*x)
        wcos[ind,0,:] = window_mask*np.cos(2*np.pi*ind/k*x)

    return wsin,wcos

wsin, wcos = create_filters(2048,2048)

wsin_var = Variable(torch.from_numpy(wsin), requires_grad=False)
wcos_var = Variable(torch.from_numpy(wcos),requires_grad=False)

network_input = torch.from_numpy(y).float()
network_input = network_input.reshape(1,-1)

zx = np.sqrt(conv1d(network_input[:,None,:], wsin_var, stride=stride).pow(2)+conv1d(network_input[:,None,:], wcos_var, stride=stride).pow(2))
pytorch_Xs = zx.cpu().numpy()
plt.plot(pytorch_Xs[0,:1025,0])
```

[image]

### My Question

The two graphs might look the same, but if I check the two outputs with `np.allclose`, we can see that they are slightly different.

```
np.allclose(S_stft, pytorch_Xs[0,:1025,0].reshape(1025,1))
output >>> False
```

Only when I tune up the tolerance to `1e-5`, it gives me `True` result

```
np.allclose(S_stft, pytorch_Xs[0,:1025,0].reshape(1025,1),atol=1e-5)
output >>> True
```

What causes the difference in values? Is it because of the data conversion by using `torch.from_numpy(y).float()`?

I would like to have a difference in value less than `1e-7`, `1e-8` is even better.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is from the difference between their default bit.
NumPy's float is 64bit by default.
PyTorch's float is 32bit by default.

Comment: I tried to verify this, but that the tolerance was still  +- 1e05 regardless of whether I fed a torch.stft a 64 bit float array or a 32 bit float array.